# C++: how to get element defined in a different function of same class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, visual-c++

I defined a class in the header file like this:

```
class myClass
{
public: 
       void test();
       void train();
private:
        bool check;
}
```

Then in the cpp file, I did this:

```
void myClass::test()
{
     int count = 9;
     //some other work
}  

void myClass::train()
{ 
    int newValue = count;
    ....
}
```

Then without surprise, I got an error saying count is not defined. So what I want to do is in my `train` function use the count value that is defined in the `test`. Is there any good way to do this without using any additional dependencies? Thank you.

Comment: defins `count` as a member variable, just like `check`?

Comment: The variable `count` only exists *inside* a call to `test()`. If you need it to persist for a given `myClass` instance, make it a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, when method test finishes its work, `count` variable does not exist anymore, so there's no way of accessing it. You have to ensure, that its lifetime will be long enough to be accessed from another place. Making it a class field solves the problem (this is what class fields are for :)).

Do it this way:

```
class myClass
{
public: 
   void test();
   void train();
private:
    bool check;
    int count; // <- here
}
```

and then

```
void myClass::test()
{
     count = 9;
     //some other work
}
```

But that's not the only solution. You can do it in another way, say:

```
class myClass
{
public: 
    int test()
    {
        // do some work
        return 9;
    }

    void train(int count)
    {
        int newValue = count;
    }
}

// (somewhere)

myClass c;
int count = c.test();
c.train(count);
```

That all depends on what `test`, `train` and `count` are for...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Well yes. That's called a member variable. Exactly like your `bool check;`.

Do

```
private:
    bool check;
    int count;
```

and then use it directly in your functions.

```
void myClass::test()
{
     count = 9;
     //Same as this->count = 9;
} 

void myClass::train()
{ 
    int newValue = count;
    //Same as int newValue = this->count;
}
```